# Bulk copy MSSQL from one server to another

Tags: c#, sql, c, sql-server

I need to bulk insert one table on one server data to another table on another server .
I am issuing command through c#, for MSSQL

But there are some constraints like :
No linked server should be used
No import export file.

SO what I want is bulk load data 
A straight forward approach where we define connections and bulk load data.

Comment: Maybe the SQL bulk copy class could work? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Isn't bulk import only for files? Between servers and tables, I'd try first SQL export and import?